# Skype shows I'm online when I don't have any Skype instance running

Tags: skype, voip, push

Recently Skype shows me as online to my contacts even when

- I do not have any instance of Skype running on my desktop
- I signed out of Skype on my mobile

Apparently, [this is a feature not a bug](http://community.skype.com/t5/Mac/I-show-up-as-Online-when-I-m-not/m-p/2367567/highlight/true#M61824). Although [many](http://community.skype.com/t5/Mac/Why-do-I-always-show-as-quot-online-quot/td-p/1038298) [people](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Skype-says-i-m-online-when-i-m-definitely-not/td-p/13882) [complained](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/My-friends-see-me-as-online-but-I-m-not-online/td-p/2925279), it seems like in the Skype world "close program" != "I'm not available". The suggested behaviour is to manually go offline in every Skype instance.

This is unacceptable, as lots of my contacts complain I'm being rude when I don't take their call or answer their IMs (it's because I'm not even running Skype!).

Is there a workaround for this that does not involve switching to a different software altogether?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Isn't the workaround right there in your question? What do you expect of answers?

Comment: @DanielBeck I was hoping I missed something. Hence my asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Skype Problem ON even when OFF:

1. Type /showplaces to a chat box to show the devices you are logged on.
2. Type /remotelogout to remotely log you off from the other devives.
3. Type /showplaces again to check

Answer (score 3):

As per the links you provided, you must change your status to "Offline" before closing the application. Until Skype changes this behavior, it seems like your only 1-step solution.

Comment: Yes, that's the only solution it seems. I just refuse to believe it has to be like that..

Comment: Your most productive course of action is to use it as is, and let your voice be heard with Skype. As you say, many people have complained and I suspect this "feature" will be reversed or adjusted to user's liking.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that skype isn't still running on your phone? It happens quite often on my Galaxy S3 where I will exit the app but it still runs in the background without the icon in the taskbar and no notifications. Usually when this happens I just go to the app info and force close it.